# Filter search Java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write filter function with Java 8 streams to filter by multiple paramaeters.

```
createdFrom - Date (mm-dd-yyyy) // if null, filter without createddate From
createdTo - Date - (mm-dd-yyyy) // if null, filter without createddate to
CreatedBy - String //if null, filter without createdby
Intaketype - List<String> // if empty, filter with all intaketypes
```

If any of the parameters is not passed, I do not want to filter by that parameter. For example If I am given createdBy null, intaketype is 'Approved' and createdfrom is 02-04-2017 createdto is 03-03-2018 then i want all approved intakes from the given dates created by all users.

```
List<Intake> intakes= intakeservice.getAllintakes.stream()
        .filter(el -> intaketype.getIntaketype.contains(el.getIntaketype())
                    && intaketype.getCreatedBy.contains(el.getCreatedBy())
        && el.getCreatedDate().before(el.dateTo)
        && el.getCreatedDate().after(el.dateFrom))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My code however,returns an empty array if any of the parameters passed is null or empty. I am not sure how to tell it to not filter by a particular parameters if not passed, empty or null.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: "For example if createdBy if null" - Can you provide a better example?

Comment: If I am given createdBy null, intaketype is 'Approved' and createdfrom is 02-04-2017 createdto is 03-03-2018 then i want all approved intakes from the given dates created by all users.

Comment: This has nothing to do with streams.  If it was a normal `if`, you would clearly do e.g. `intakeType.getCreatedBy() == null || intakeType.getCreatedBy().contains(el.getCreatedBy())`.   It's the same here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman It doesn't work actually...I am getting an empty array now..

Comment: Then you need to debug your logic.  Again: this has nothing to do with streams, only with writing your logic correctly to check for null and respond appropriately.

Comment: It's not the logic. I think my question is how to omit a filter criteria if it not passed or null.

Comment: @RamKumar I think LouisWasserman is right. Could you update your code with the (==null) conditions so we can see what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @HenriqueOrdine Yes he's right. It was my logic actually..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create multiple .filter(), where you describe logic for one rule. The .filter() rules are with logical AND in the stream, i.e. if one of the .filter() rules is false, then this will not be processed.

```
List<Intake> intakes= intakeservice.getAllintakes.stream()
    .filter(el -> Objects.isNull(el.dateTo) || el.getCreatedDate().before(el.dateTo))
    .filter(el -> Objects.isNull(el.dateFrom) || el.getCreatedDate().after(el.dateFrom))
    .filter(el -> Objects.isNull(el.getCreatedBy) || intaketype.getCreatedBy.contains(el.getCreatedBy()))
    .filter(el -> Objects.isNull(el.getIntaketype) || el.getIntaketype.size == 0 || intaketype.getIntaketype.contains(el.getIntaketype())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Let's dig into one of the rules:
el -> Objects.isNull(el.dateTo) || el.getCreatedDate().before(el.dateTo)

If dateTo is null, then the result of the lambda is true.
if dateTo is not null, then result is the comparison of the dateTo with el.getCreatedDate()

If the .filter() is false, then this record will be filtered and not proccessed down the stream.